# Sklearn cross_val_score gives significantly different number than model.score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I have a binary classification problem

First I train test split my data as:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)
```

I checked the y_train and it had basically a 50/50 split of the two classes (1,0) which is how the dataset it

when I try a base model such as:

```
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.score(X_train, y_train)
```

the output is `0.98` or something 1% different depending on the random state of the train test split.

HOWEVER, when I try a cross_val_score such as:

```
cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=StratifiedKFold(shuffle=True), scoring='accuracy')
```

the output is

```
array([0.65      , 0.78333333, 0.78333333, 0.66666667, 0.76666667])
```

none of the scores in the array are even close to 0.98?

and when I tried scoring = 'r2' I got

```
>>>cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=StratifiedKFold(shuffle=True), scoring='r2')
array([-0.20133482, -0.00111235, -0.2       , -0.2       , -0.13333333])
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I have tried `Shuffle` = `True` and `False` but it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why is it Z_train instead of X_train? are you sure its training the right stuff

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in StackOverflow, not in the actual code, thanks for pointing that out though

Comment: @iLoveItWhenUCallMeBigData Do you compute the score on the training set or is it a typo too ?

Comment: yeah.. if you compute on the training set, then the model has used the train data to fit. A fairer comparison is to calculate the score on test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your base model, you compute your score on the training corpus. While this is a proper way to ensure your model has actually learnt from the data you fed it, it doesn't ensure the final accuracy of your model on new and unseen data.

Not 100% sure (I don't know well scikit-learn), but I'd expect `cross_val_score` to actually split the `X_train` and `y_train` into a training and a testing set.

So as you compute a score on data unseen during the training, the accuracy will be much lower. Try to compare these results with `model.score(X_test, y_test)`, it should be much closer.

Comment: Ah you are right, I thought that the output of cross val was an output of how well the model fits the training data (which is a valid thing to do and necessary to check for over fitting so idk why ppl in the comments are upset by this... anyway). You are right that it trains on n-1 folds and the output is the last fold as a test. thank you

Comment: @iLoveItWhenUCallMeBigData Glad it helped ;)